# Inheriting CSS how do I stop it?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I know what the problem I am having is but I can't figure out how to stop it.

I have an element with an `id` of `footer`, and another element inside that one with a class of `socialmedia`. I am using a sprite to handle the media icons. The problem I am having is that `#footer ul li`'s padding (`padding: 9px 0px 9px 13px`) is being inherited by `.socialmedia`.

I have tried adding `.socialmedia ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}` to stop it and I have also added `!Important` but the padding still seems to get through.

I want to remove the left padding of 13px from the social media icons so they aren't so spaced. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have created a JFiddle if you want to see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Nv59/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News & Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="FooterAddress"><strong>ABC Comp</strong><br>555 My Street.<br>Boonton, CA 07005<br>1 (800) 555-1111<br><br>

          <div class="socialmedia">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://facebook.com" title="Be our friend" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com" title="Let's connect" target="_blank" class="linked"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us!" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

       </div>


    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Footer */

#footer {background-color: #3B3014; height: 150px; margin-top: 10px;}
#footer ul {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
#footer ul li{display: inline-block; padding: 9px 0px 9px 13px;}
#footer ul li a {text-decoration: none; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;}
#footer ul li a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FF6600; font-weight: bold;}
.FooterAddress {float: right; color: #FFC50B; font-size: 11px; margin-right: 13px; margin-top:-20px; text-align:right;}
.developedby {float: left; color: #fff; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 13px; margin-top: 94px;}
.developedby a {color: #FFC50B; text-decoration:none;}
.developedby a:hover {color: #CCC;cursor:hand;}

/* Soecial Media Sprites */
.nopadding {padding: 0px;float: right; color: #fff; background: #000;}
.socialmedia ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.socialmedia ul li a {display: block; width: 26px; height: 27px; background: url(../images/socialmedia_sprite_sm.png) no-repeat; padding: 0px;}
.socialmedia ul li:last-child {margin-right: 0;}

.socialmedia a.facebook {background-position: -27px -27px;}
.socialmedia a.facebook:hover {background-position: -27px 0;}
.socialmedia a.linked {background-position: -52px -27px;}
.socialmedia a.linked:hover {background-position: -52px 0;}
.socialmedia a.twitter {background-position: left bottom;}
.socialmedia a.twitter:hover {background-position: left top;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get more specific.

Change:

```css
.socialmedia ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

to

```css
#footer .socialmedia ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2Nv59/5/)**

You had the right idea but the `#footer ul li` rule is more specific, so it's CSS was overriding your other rule. You can learn more about CSS specificity at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Uggg I want to SCREAM!!! Why... I knew I was close but I thought that since the socialmedia css loads after the footer that it would override the footer padding. I guess like you said I really how to hon in to detail to make sure I am targeting something right. Thank you!

Comment: Meh, do what I do when coding pisses me off, go have a drink or four.

Comment: @FrankG. the order of rules only comes into play if the rules have selectors or equal specificity. CSS specificity tends to make sense once you learn it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I have learned it studying the lyndia videos but there soooooo much to remember that it hard for someone learning. I wish there was some type of app, program or site that could help me target things better. I have always had a hard time targeting things in css. I don't know why but even when I think I've hit the target I missed it with something simple like that.

Comment: @FrankG.: sure, it takes a while to get the best ways lodged in your head. A good rule of thumb is to make your selectors as specific (not in the sense of CSS specificity, but in the sense of how many elements they apply to) as possible to begin with. [I've gone into more detail in my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19732168/20578)

Comment: @Dude I took a look at your http://cssspecificity.com/ but that just confuses the hell out of me haha. I not sure I can even flow what's going on with that. :( Any help walking me thu what is going on there?

Comment: @FrankG. There are several levels of importance. *, element, class or psudo, inline, !important. Each level is infinitely more important than the last. http://cssspecificity.com has it all in order from least to most important. http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Dude that last link was very helpful although still confused I think over time I will grasp the concept. I need to read more about it so I can actually get it and understand it 100% because that will be problems for me in the future if I don't and as you see in this post targeting is a problem I have always struggled with in css. Thank yoU!

Comment: @FrankG. Your welcome. Anytime you get confused, you could just refer to the links. Also play around with the web inspector.

Answer (score 3):

try adding `#footer .socialmedia ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}`
to override css rules in children elements your css selector should be more specific than the one you are trying to override.

Comment: I never thought of that ugg... I knew I was getting close but I figured since the socialmedia was loading after footer that the social media would win with removing padding. I understand what you did which says to target footer then social media by doing the #footer .socialmedia.... ugg I hate when I miss simple things like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because the ID selector has higher specificity than any other CSS rule, it can be helpful to steer clear of using it, at least in broadly applicable selectors like `#footer ul li`.

Although the answers provided already will solve your problem, it might be better to change your *original* selector to be more specific, as you don't seem to want any of its styles to apply to the social media `<li>`s. For example:

#### HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        ....
```

#### CSS

```
#footer .navigation li{display: inline-block; padding: 9px 0px 9px 13px;}
```